# payable extension required?

Tags: solidity, payable, voting

I am writing a simple contract to replicate a voting session led by a president. The contract compiles correctly, however, I can't deploy it because of the following error: "Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information." .

I can't see why I need a payable modifier on the constructor. The code is the following:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.6;

contract Voting{

    address public president;

    mapping(bytes32=>uint) public candidates;

    bytes32[] public names;

    constructor(bytes32[] memory _names) {
        president = msg.sender;
        for(uint idx=0; idx<_names.length; idx++){
            bytes32 name = _names[idx];
            names[idx] = name;
            candidates[name] = 0;
        }
    }

    function vote(bytes32 name) public {
        candidates[name] += 1;
    }

    function declareWinner() public view returns(bytes32){
        require(president==msg.sender);
        bytes32 winner;
        uint votes=0;

        for(uint idx=0; idx<names.length; idx++){
            bytes32 name = names[idx];
            uint _votes = candidates[name];
            if(_votes > votes){
                winner = name;
                votes = _votes;
            }
        }

        return winner;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you are not sending any eth to the contract while deploying it.
I tried that code on Remix and it worked alright.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I wasn't sending any ether even the first time, but it didn't work. However, once I changed the constructor as

    `constructor(bytes32[] memory _names) public {
        president = msg.sender;
        names = _names; // changed this
        for(uint idx=0; idx<_names.length; idx++){
            bytes32 name = _names[idx];
            candidates[name] = 0;
        }
    }`

now it works... very strange